# How to get variable, array, nodelist from different function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, undefined

I am trying to write a ToDoList with JavaScript.

I have an **input-element**. Whenever I type something and press enter, it creates a new fieldset(in my example its a fieldset but it can also be a Div) with the class name ".fieldListClass" and a P-Tag as a child of fieldset. the P-tag innerHTML is the the value of input. I used Click-EventListener for that.

After each click, I assigned the query selector of all .fieldListClass to a nodeList "fieldListQuery". I even converted this nodeList into an Array but no result.

Now I want to create an addEventListner but outside the previous one. it should be a new one. And It should be a click-EventListener for all **fieldListQuery** which where created inside the previous function.(this part is at the bottom of my code)

When I click on it something should happen like removing the current target etc. But it wont work because outside the function it always says that this variable is undefined. I don't get it because I declared it global outside of the function.

I don't want to use DOMNodeInserted or MutationObserver yet for detecting changes inside the DOM. Simple because the first one is not recommended anymore it and the last one I have no idea how to use it. Many people saying that this is not a safe way.

Any Help please?

```
let addDiv = document.createElement("div"); addDiv.id = "addDivId";
let listDiv = document.createElement("div"); listDiv.id = "listDivId";
let inputText = document.createElement("input"); inputText.id = "inputTextId";
let fieldList; // = document.createElement("fieldset");
let fieldDiv; // = document.createElement("div");
let fieldDivP; // = document.createElement("P");
let fieldListArr;
let fieldListQuery;

document.body.appendChild(addDiv);
addDiv.appendChild(inputText);
document.body.appendChild(listDiv);

inputText.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
 fieldList = document.createElement("fieldset");
 fieldDiv = document.createElement("div");
 fieldDivP = document.createElement("P");

 listDiv.appendChild(fieldList);
 fieldList.className = "fieldListClass";
 fieldList.appendChild(fieldDiv);
 fieldDiv.appendChild(fieldDivP);
 fieldDivP.innerHTML = inputText.value;

 fieldListQuery = document.querySelectorAll(".fieldListClass") ;

  }
})

fieldListQuery.forEach(element => {  // <- it say fieldListQuery is undefined.
 fieldListQuery.addEventListener("click", e =>  {
e.currentTarget.innerHTML="test";
})
});

´´´
```

Comment: Why do you use the `fieldset` element the way you do? `fieldset` is pretty much only for grouping form controls.

Comment: `fieldListQuery` is set in the event listener for `inputText`. So, it is undefined when you load the page.

Comment: Looking at your code, I can't help but wonder what are you actually trying to implement? You have way too many `createElement` calls, and some of the statements in your snippet make little sense -- assigning `fieldListArr` on every iteration of the `fieldListQuery` loop isn't required -- the value does not depend on the effect of the loop statement. If you edit your question and add more detail about your desired functionality as part of your ToDoList application, one could conceivably offer you a shorter and more concise code that you can learn and benefit from.

Comment: @amn I am using fieldset just for testing and because if you disable a fieldset then everything inside will be disabled too. I could change it into Div if that is better. And I assigned fieldListArr just for testing purpose, because I read that it is easier to deal with Array instead of a NodeList. I also used many createElement coz I wanted to use DOM create all the html tags with Javascript. Do you think there is a easier way to do that? And yes, I will try to write my question better later. and as for the code here, I will remove the loop function with the array.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey but wont it be defined after one click? wont Javascrip look at this again or just at the beginning when page is loaded?

Comment: JavaScript is mostly event-driven. It only looks at code because something happened, and you've told it that when something happens, "run this code". Because the code with `fieldListQuery.forEach(...` is not in an event listener, it's run when the script is parsed, and that's it.

Comment: Disabling a fieldset only disables *form controls*. You are going by some subjective definition of "disabling". There is a *dozen* of ways to "disable" elements in HTML. Your using fieldsets because of *how* they work instead of *what they are for* will create problems for you in the long run. So I'd always advise anyone to go by purpose of elements, not how they are implemented (even by specification). Anyway, I will try to write some more idiomatic form to address your procedure, but it sure would be nice if you described what you're designing conceptually, thanks.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey good to know, thank. If I add this `fieldListQuery.forEach(...` inside the click eventListener function of inputtext then it works. is this the normal way of doing it? It just doesnt look nice to me

Comment: @amn I definetly will make rewrite this code again to make it way prettier and will try to rephrase my question to make it more detail. Do you think it would be a problem for others to read if I only use javascript to create the elements? because I dont want to confuse the others...

Answer (score 1):

Since I offered critique of your approach, I thought it is only fair I at least try to offer you some code that accomplishes (on the overall level, in light of absence of much detail about your solution) something along of what you have.

First off, I think creating trees of elements through a script when other solutions are more viable, tends to show an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). Your script is invariably loaded in the context of an HTML document, which may already contain a lot of useful markup -- including an input field (that you were creating with `createElement`). If the input field is a "constant" there is no need to waste code on creating it -- just put it in your markup.

Second, even for elements or hierarchies of elements that are created "on demand" -- as a reaction to an event or however else -- it typically is much more readable and manageable to use *templates*. As a fallback -- if `template` cannot be used for some reason -- using `innerHTML` to create entire element trees is actually an appealing and more readable option than a lot of "boilerplate" containing `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc.

Third, you should always try to see if you can have your interactive controls be part of a form. I won't go into all reasons to do so, but suffice to say it helps user agents that screen-read content and for other accessibility systems, to name one. There are exceptions to this rule, but I don't recall looking at code where a control should not be part of a form -- so the rule is a good one.

Here is a proof-of-concept bare-bones to-do application:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function submit_create_todo_item_form() {
                const new_todo_fragment = document.getElementById("todo-item-template").content.cloneNode(true);
                new_todo_fragment.querySelector(".body").textContent = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
                document.body.appendChild(new_todo_fragment);
            }
        </script>
        <template id="todo-item-template">
            <div class="todo-item"> 
                <p class="body"></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="javascript: submit_create_todo_item_form()">
            <input>
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

Take note that I use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` to create content for a to-do item's body. `innerHTML` invokes the HTML parser and unless you plan to be typing *hypertext* into that single line of `input` field, `innerHTML` only costs you extra for no clear benefit. If you need to interpret the value *verbatim*, `textContent` is instead exactly what's needed. So, approach your solution with that in mind.

I hope this is useful, I worked with what I thought I had.

Comment: Sir, your approach is way better than what ever I was planing to do! I see, I have to learn more. I have to rewrite my whole code. Your code is incredibly useful and I am looking forward to play with that. I see you took advantage of `form-element`  and you did not add eventListener at all and u also are using `cloneNode`. Thank you! I missed the last days of my JavaScript class where we had all of this.

Comment: The set of usable Web technologies is a treasure trove / rats nest of features that changes rapidly over time. I still pick up new things occasionally, all after having written my first line of JavaScript code two decades ago. Like I said, try to incorporate templates where they make sense -- when you would otherwise need have to create element trees with JS alone. Use `form` whenever you have interactive controls, as a rule. Always check for user agent support, too -- a lot of features are too fresh and don't work in all the popular user agents. Good luck with the learning curve :)

Comment: I just want to thank you again. My teachers always told me that we should never use javacode inside html. In your example it is ` <form action="javascript: submit_create_todo_item_form()">` this line I was able to write it in javascript `document.querySelector(".form").action = "javascript: submit_create_todo_item_form()";`.  With `<p class="body"></p>` I added an onClick function inside this tag. it now looks like that `<p class="body" onclick="editFunction(event)"></p>` What I noticed it when the elements are not existing inside the DOM yet, then addEventlistener wont work. Is that true?

Comment: You should ask your teachers for an alternative way to submit a form with JavaScript, then. I don't know of any. Responding to "submit" event is not it -- first off, it isn't fired in all case of form submission, and second, its purpose is to instead let one handle side-effects of submission, as opposed to submission itself. As for setting the `action` attribute with a script -- that's ok, maybe even better, yes. But I think this kind of information should be communicated with HTML, just as if it was a form with a HTTP action.

Comment: As for non-existing elements and event listeners -- obviously, if you attempt to invoke `addEventListener` on a `null` reference, you will get a runtime error (that is unrelated to `addEventListener` -- you can't access a property, including a function, on `null`). But you can attach an event listener to some ancestor element (that exists), and events will bubble up -- very useful in a lot of cases. I don't recommend you use `onclick` kind of attributes -- for the same reason your teachers probably don't recommend `javascript:` action in HTML -- separation of markup and script.

Comment: Thats very good information, thank you. I dont like to use onclick as well. So I definetley have to rethink and look for ancestor elements and add click event to the "future" children if that works.